# Color when visualizing latex table in orgmode

Tags: org-mode, colors, preview-latex

I am using Emacs + orgmode to write text and latex equations. The preview within orgmode (with `C-c C-x C-l`) works well for latex equations.
However, I noticed that if I display a latex table within orgmode, it uses a black font color, so it is almost invisible in a dark background (screenshot below).

[image]

**Question:** Is it possible to change the font color for previewed tables to be the same as the font color for latex math?

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak this by customizing the variable `org-format-latex-options`. In particular, set the :foreground option to `auto` to match the text face, or `default` to match the default face.

Comment: Hey Tyler, thanks for the suggestion, but it does not seem to work. Changing to `:foreground auto` and previewing the table leads to the error `Invalid face`. The weird thing is that the color is correct for math equations (`$...$` and `\begin{align}...\end{align}`), but not for tables (`\begin{table}...\end{table}`).

Comment: I have tried this multiple times again, and also changing my `init.el`, but still no success.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. You're right - the settings seem to work only for equations, not tables. As far as I can tell org handles equations and tables exactly the same, but for some reason the dvipng program doesn't apply the color setting to tables.